# Plotting numerous disconnected line segments with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I have a set of data records like this:

```
(s1, t1), (u1, v1), color1
(s2, t2), (u2, v2), color2
.
.
.
(sN, tN), (uN, vN), colorN
```

In any record, the first two values are the **end-points** of a line segment, the third value is the **color** of that line segment. More specifically, `(sn, tn)` are the x-y coordinates of the first end-point, `(un, vn)` are the x-y coordinates of the second-endpoint. Also, **color** is an rgb with alpha value.

In general, any two line segments are **disconnected** (meaning that their end-points do not necessarily coincide).

How to plot this data using **matplotlib** with a single `plot` call (or as few as possible) as there could be potentially thousands of records.

## Attempts

Preparing the data in one big list and calling `plot` against it is way too slow. For example the following code couldn't finish in a reasonable amount of time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
for _ in xrange(60000):
    data.append((np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()))
    data.append((np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()))
    data.append('r')

print 'now plotting...' # from now on, takes too long
plt.plot(*data)
print 'done'
#plt.show()
```

I was able to speed-up the plot rendering by using the **None** insertion trick as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import timeit

N = 60000
_s = np.random.rand(N)
_t = np.random.rand(N)
_u = np.random.rand(N)
_v = np.random.rand(N)
x = []
y = []
for s, t, u, v in zip(_s, _t, _u, _v):
    x.append(s)
    x.append(u)
    x.append(None)
    y.append(t)
    y.append(v)
    y.append(None)
print timeit(lambda:plt.plot(x, y), number=1)
```

This executes in under a second on my machine. I still have to figure out how to embed the color values (RGB with alpha channel).

Comment: does using `nan` instead of `None` make any difference, it results in the same plot but I can use `numpy.tile` and `numpy.repeat` to build `x` and `y` instead of appending to list. Also did you figure out if you can embed the color with this (not like the `LineColelction` method)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I ended up rasterising the lines on a PIL image before converting it to a numpy array:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import random as rnd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 60000
s = (500, 500)

im = Image.new('RGBA', s, (255,255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

for i in range(N):
    x1 = rnd.random() * s[0]
    y1 = rnd.random() * s[1]
    x2 = rnd.random() * s[0]
    y2 = rnd.random() * s[1]
    alpha = rnd.random()
    color  = (int(rnd.random() * 256), int(rnd.random() * 256), int(rnd.random() * 256), int(alpha * 256)) 
    draw.line(((x1,y1),(x2,y2)), fill=color, width=1)

plt.imshow(np.asarray(im),
           origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

This is by far the fastest solution and it fits my real-time needs perfectly. One caveat though is the lines are drawn without anti-aliasing.

Comment: Out of laziness, I would suggest `rgba = (np.random.randint(256) for _ in range(4))`.

Answer (score 121):

use [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

lines = [[(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]]
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I tried that, it's still not fast enough for 60000 lines, right?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: absolutely! in fact I wanted to add a similar update to the question but decided not to out of sheer laziness.

Comment: Unbelievable response! Brilliant!

Comment: Great answer, this is the only solution I've found using matplotlib that can handle a large number of lines efficiently. For ~2000 lines it's 60 milliseconds instead of 1.6 seconds for other techniques.

Comment: Is it possible to delete such collection? I mean, I'm using a slider to add a collection and if the slider val is less I'd like to delete the previous collection to add a new one (with less lines).

Comment: @zhangxaochen Maybe hardware got faster but it is now. 62k lines in about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 19):

function `plot` allows to draw multiple lines in one call, if your data is just in a list, just unpack it when passing it to `plot`:

```
In [315]: data=[(1, 1), (2, 3), 'r', #assuming points are (1,2) (1,3) actually and,
                                     #here they are in form of (x1, x2), (y1, y2)
     ...: (2, 2), (4, 5), 'g',
     ...: (5, 5), (6, 7), 'b',]

In [316]: plot(*data)
Out[316]: 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x8752870>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x8752a30>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x8752db0>]
```

[image]

Comment: @user698585 did you try it? see my pasted picture. I'm assuming your `(s1, t1), (u1, v1)` is in form of `(x1, x2), (y1, y2)`, otherwise you should zip `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` to `(x1, x2), (y1, y2)` first

Comment: sorry the question wasn't clear enough, check the update. Anyway, I get your point. You might want to update your answer to be compatible with what is specifically stated in the question as it stands right now.

Comment: I've tried it on my actual dataset. this is still too slow, if you have 60,000 (the actual number of records) segments then you're calling a function with ~ 60,000 params!! inefficient

Comment: @user698585 that's what you asked for(with a single **plot** call)... Nobody says it's effiecient with 60,000 lines drawn on a single figure, either with a single call or calls in a for loop.

Comment: actually looping would have been faster than what you did, this was my first attempt

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, check my second update as I was able to achieve considerable speed-up. Maybe you can help with the color thing?

Comment: @user698585, your **Update 2** is drawing one line in the figure, thus generates only one `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object, I'm guessing that's why it speeds up. Yet I don't know if there's a way to draw one line with multiple colors... sorry for that

Comment: How would you use the unpack operator in 3D?

Comment: @seralouk see: https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558

Answer (score 3):

I have tried a good few 2D rendering engines available on Python 3, while looking for a fast solution for an output stage in image-oriented Deep Learning & GAN.

Using the following benchmark: Time to render 99 lines into a 256x256 off-screen image (or whatever is more effective) with and without anti-alias.

The results, in order of efficiency on my oldish x301 laptop:

- PyGtk2: ~2500 FPS, (Python 2, GTK 2, not sure how to get AA)
- PyQt5: ~1200 FPS, ~350 with Antialias
- PyQt4: ~1100 FPS, ~380 with AA
- Cairo: ~750 FPS, ~250 with AA (only slightly faster with 'FAST' AA)
- PIL: ~600 FPS

The baseline is a loop which takes ~0.1 ms (10,000 FPS) retrieving random numbers and calling the primitives.

Basic code for PyGtk2:

```
from gtk import gdk
import random

WIDTH = 256
def r255(): return int(256.0*random.random())

cmap = gdk.Colormap(gdk.visual_get_best_with_depth(24), True)
black = cmap.alloc_color('black')
white = cmap.alloc_color('white')
pixmap = gdk.Pixmap(None, WIDTH, WIDTH, 24)
pixmap.set_colormap(cmap)
gc = pixmap.new_gc(black, line_width=2)
pixmap.draw_rectangle(gc, True, -1, -1, WIDTH+2, WIDTH+2);
gc.set_foreground(white)
for n in range(99):
    pixmap.draw_line(gc, r255(), r255(), r255(), r255())

gdk.Pixbuf(gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, WIDTH, WIDTH
    ).get_from_drawable(pixmap, cmap, 0,0, 0,0, WIDTH, WIDTH
        ).save('Gdk2-lines.png','png')
```

And here is for PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import random

WIDTH = 256.0
def r255(): return WIDTH*random.random()

image = QImage(WIDTH, WIDTH, QImage.Format_RGB16)
painter = QPainter()
image.fill(Qt.black)
painter.begin(image)
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 2))
#painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
for n in range(99):
    painter.drawLine(WIDTH*r0to1(),WIDTH*r0to1(),WIDTH*r0to1(),WIDTH*r0to1())    
painter.end()
image.save('Qt5-lines.png', 'png')
```

And here is Python3-Cairo for completeness:

```
import cairo
from random import random as r0to1

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 256, 256

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_A8, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.scale(WIDTH, HEIGHT)  # Normalizing the canvas
ctx.set_line_width(0.01)
ctx.set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
ctx.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_NONE)
#ctx.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_FAST)

ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_CLEAR)
ctx.paint()
ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
for n in range(99):
    ctx.move_to(r0to1(), r0to1())
    ctx.line_to(r0to1(), r0to1())
    ctx.stroke()

surface.write_to_png('Cairo-lines.png')
```