# Using datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime

*Part 1* below illustrates using datetime objects to plot a curve.

[*Part 2*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357666/704972) illustrates using floats to plot a set of segments.

*Part 3* merely blends Parts 1 & 2, but it fails. Why?

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

#----------------Part 1----------------
d0 = datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1)
d1 = datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 1)
d3 = datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1)
d4 = datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 1)
d5 = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1)

date  = [ d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 ]
price = [ 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 8 ]

plt.plot(date, price)
plt.show()

#----------------Part 2----------------
lines = [ [ (0.5, 1.2), (1.1, 1.3) ],
          [ (2.2, 2.8), (3.1, 4.2) ],
          [ (1.9, 2.9), (0.2, 1.4) ] ]

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()

#----------------Part 3----------------
lines = [ [ (d0, 1.2), (d1, 1.3) ],
          [ (d2, 2.8), (d3, 4.2) ],
          [ (d4, 2.9), (d5, 1.4) ] ]

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)

plt.show()
```

*Update*

The line

```
lc = mc.LineCollection(lines)
```

in Part 3 bails out with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datetime-difficulty.py", line 37, in <module>
    lc = mc.LineCollection(lines)
  File "/lib/python/matplotlib/collections.py", line 897, in __init__
    self.set_segments(segments)
  File "/lib/python/matplotlib/collections.py", line 906, in set_segments
    seg = np.asarray(seg, np.float_)
  File "/lib/python/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: @alfasin Updated: "float() argument must be a string or a number"

Comment: Well, that means that `LineCollection()` accepts line with a float as the first argument in every tuple, not a date-object ;)

Comment: @alfasin I could compute and pass some floats, but then the x-labels will be meaningless. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using `matplotlib`, so you'll need to convert your dates into floats in order for your plots to work.  Thankfully, `matplotlib` supplies the [date2num()](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) function.  Run all of your dates through that function, and `matplotlib` should be able to give you a meaningful x-axis (depending on formatter / locator).

Comment: But then the x labels are meaningless, and moving the cursor to a point in the diagram gives a meaningless x-coordinate. As Part 1 illustrates, matplotlib already handles datetime just fine.

Comment: @Calaf just because it manages to handle datetime doesn't mean it can combine it with non datetime on the same axis.