# Two point segment plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I plot a two point line segment plot as shown in the following figure
[image]

The data is like below

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

y = [1.2,1.2,-2.1, -2.1, 4.1, -4.1]   #these y values are always in pair such that I need a solid line to connect these equivalent values and then a dotted line between this pair and the next pair.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this achieve what you were hoping?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.1, -4.1, -4.1]

plt.plot(x, y, 'm--')

pair_x_array = np.reshape(x, (-1, 2))
pair_y_array = np.reshape(y, (-1, 2))
for i, pair_x in enumerate(pair_x_array):
    pair_y = pair_y_array[i]
    plt.plot(pair_x, pair_y, 'm', linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pylab
xdata = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ydata = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
# Assuming xdata, ydata are of suitable length and type
plots = [pylab.plot(xdata[i:i + 2], ydata[i:i + 2], **whatever_keyword_arguments) for i in xrange(0, len(xdata), 2)]
pylab.show()
```

---

Edit after OP edit:

I see what you mean, and it's trivial to add the lines in dashes.

```
def plot_broken(xseq, yseq, even=True, **plot_kwargs):
    size = len(xseq)
    assert size == len(yseq)
    assert size % 2 == 0
    start = 0 if even else 1
    return [pylab.plot(xseq[i:i + 2], yseq[i:i + 2], **plot_kwargs)
            for i in xrange(start, size, 2)]
plots = plot_broken(xdata, ydata, even=True, color="m",
                    linestyle="solid")
plots += plot_broken(xdata, ydata, even=False, color="m",
                     linestyle="dashed")
```

Comment: Looks a little more complicated compared to MeshachBlue's answer.

Comment: @user274642 Impossible.  Both are O(n) in terms of line segments plotted ;)

Comment: Hehe :) just a different style :)