# Markers at the ends of hlines in matplolib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to run this exact code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#xs = np.linspace(1, 21, 200)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
plt.hlines(y='Test1', xmin=1929, xmax=1978, colors='red', linestyles='-', lw=2, label='Test1')
plt.hlines(y='Test2', xmin=1800, xmax=1991, colors='blue', linestyles='-', lw=2, label='Test2')
plt.hlines(y='Test3', xmin=1930, xmax=2007, colors='green', linestyles='-', lw=2, label='Test3')
plt.show()
```

And get this exact output:

[image]

However, I want markers (circles) at either end of each line.

Markers don't seem to be an option in hlines, from the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html).

Can someone suggest an alternative to reproducing the same graph, but with markers [like these](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268211/adding-line-markers-when-using-linecollection

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know the word 'LineCollection' so it didn't come up, thanks.

Comment: [https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the goal using regular plot like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
plt.plot([1929, 1978], ['Test1', 'Test1'], '-o', color='red')
plt.plot([1800, 1991], ['Test2', 'Test2'], '-o', color='blue')
plt.plot([1930, 2007], ['Test3', 'Test3'], '-o', color='green')
```

This will result in:

[image]

Edit from @LorenaGil:

In case one want's the marker at the end of the line one can use the `markevery` argument like the following:

```
 plt.plot([1929, 1978], ['Test1', 'Test1'], '-o', color='red', markevery=[-1])
```

Comment: Moreover, if you only want the markers on the end of the line you can use the parameter markevery, like follows:
plt.plot([1929, 1978], ['Test1', 'Test1'], '-o', color='red', markevery=[-1])

Comment: @LorenaGil True, but the OP said in both ends. But nice remark, I'll add it to the answer.