# Line segment plotting in Python

Tags: python, r, visualization

I'm trying to plot data for research. It should look like this,

[image: Segment plot]

This was drawn with R. I was wondering if there is any way to draw something like this in Python? Each segment has their own start and end from 2 variables that are in `x`. `y` is just the IDs of the samples.

Here is the R code,

```
df <- read.table("df.hom",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

p1 <- ggplot(df[which(df$PHE == 2),])

p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes(x=POS1, xend=POS2, y=IID, yend=IID), size=5)

p1 <- p1 + xlab("Position (in Mb)") + ylab("Sample")

p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()

p1
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors)

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work for you?

Comment: I tried https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#segments-and-rays but with no luck, every time I get this error : "Glyph refers to nonexistent column name" and I get an empty plot.