# Using List contents in variable returns "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'" error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to write a script that will pull data from a CSV, then create line segments at y-values corresponding to the data using .linecollection (similar to the method shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357666/4488288)

I am  able to create a list from the csv file, but am getting a 
`"TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'"`error.

I'm using python 3.7.3

I'm new to matplotlib and have not used python in many years, so any help would be great - I'm not tied to needing this particular method, only inputting csv files and outputting diagrams.

(I am attempting to create simple nuclear energy level diagrams/grotrian charts - none of the solutions I have encountered have worked for my needs)

I've attempted using list(map(float and got

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Collecting data from csv:

```
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count < 10:
            angmom0.append({row[0]})
            energy0.append({row[1]})
            line_count += 1
```

Attempting to Write contents of list (I'm only attempting for one entry in the list to simplify)

```
lines = [[(0, energy0[0]), (1,energy0[0])], [(2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]]
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])
```

Expected output would be a chart, similar to (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srl6l.png).][1](http://%20(I%20am%20attempting%20to%20create%20simple%20nuclear%20energy%20level%20diagrams/grotrian%20charts%20-%20none%20of%20the%20solutions%20I%20have%20encountered%20have%20worked%20for%20my%20needs))

I'm currently unable to produce any output at all

**Edit**

The curly brackets were the problem! Thanks for the help everyone!!

Comment: What are the curly bracket for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `{row[0]}` and `{row[1]}`, when collecting data from `csv` file, which basically creates a `set` that has one element. I am not sure, but you may wanted to use `f strings` like this `f'{row[0]}'`. You can just remove `{}` and do `row[0]` instead since it is a string anyway. I am not sure if this is the problem, but I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
angmom0.append({row[0]})
```

You are appending a set with `row[0]` to the `angmom0` list. A set is a builtin in python which is a collection of unordered, unique elements. For example, {4, 5, 6, 2} is a set. You create them by writing curly brackets, then a sequence of elements inside the curly brackets. In your case, the single element will be `row[0]`.

I don't know the exact format of your CSV so I can't tell for sure, however you probably just want to do `angmom0.append(row[0])` :)