# Plotting graph in python- LineCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

Can I simplify `lines` somehow?

From this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lines = np.array([[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]])
line_coll = LineCollection(lines,colors='red')
ax.add_collection(line_coll)
lines = np.array([[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]])
line_coll = LineCollection(lines,colors='red')
ax.add_collection(line_coll)


plt.xlim([0, lines[:,:,0].max()])
plt.ylim([0, lines[:,:,1].max()])
```

to something like this or shorter:

```py
lines = np.array([[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]])
lines = np.array([[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]])
line_coll = LineCollection(lines,colors='red')
ax.add_collection(line_coll)
```

I dont want to add still

```py
line_coll = LineCollection(lines,colors='red')
ax.add_collection(line_coll)
```

for every `lines`

---

**EDIT:**

here is my loop:

```py
while i <= n:
    if i == 0:
        #code
        lines= np.array([[[0, R], [x[i], 0]]])
        #line_coll= LineCollection(lines,colors= 'red')
        #ax.add_collection(line_coll)

    elif i == n:
        #code
        lines = np.array([[[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]],
                         [[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]])
        #for line in lines:
        #    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
        #    ax.add_collection(line_coll)   

    else: 
        #code
        lines = np.array([[[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]],
                         [[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]])
        #for line in lines:
        #    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
        #    ax.add_collection(line_coll)
    i= i+1 

#how can i add one loop for all "lines" above?  This below doesnt work good  
for line in lines:
    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
    ax.add_collection(line_coll)
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

```py
while i <= n:
    if i == 0:
        #code
        lines.append(np.array([[[0, R], [x[i], 0]]]))      
    elif i == n:
        #code
        lines.append(np.array([[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]], [[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]))

    else: 
        #code
        lines.append(np.array([[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]], [[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]))

    i= i+1 

for line in lines:
    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
    ax.add_collection(line_coll)
```

`while` loop above works (I had to delete some `[]`) good if i set:

```py
plt.xlim([0, 60])
plt.ylim([0, 60])
```

It doesnt if I set this:

```py
plt.xlim([0, lines[:,:,0].max()])
plt.ylim([0, lines[:,:,1].max()])
```

There is error `list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` 
for `plt.xlim([0, lines[:,:,0].max()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your lines into an array and then loop over the array and add one line artist at a time. The code would look something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lines = np.array([[[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]],
                 [[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]])
for line in lines:
    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
    ax.add_collection(line_coll)

plt.xlim([0, lines[:,:,0].max()])
plt.ylim([0, lines[:,:,1].max()])
```

**EDIT** Try the following trick

```
lines = []

while i <= n:
    if i == 0:
        #Code here
        lines.append(np.array([[[0, R], [x[i], 0]]]))
    elif i == n:
        #Code here
        lines.append(np.array([[[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]],
                         [[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]]))
    else: 
       #Code here
        lines.append(np.array([[[[x[i-1], y[i-1]], [x[i], y[i]]]],
                         [[[0, R], [x[i], y[i]]]]]))
    i= i+1 

for line in lines:
    line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')
    ax.add_collection(line_coll)
```

Comment: I think the question is how to only use a single LineCollection, not several.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I see, I thought he/she wants to avoid multiple LineCollection commands.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357666/4932316) already plot several lines in a single command?

Comment: Sure, it's not at all obvious why they start with two LineCollections in the first place.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you see my 'edit' and help?

Comment: @Sheldore there is an error ```'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2``` refers to ```line_coll = LineCollection(line, colors='red')```

Comment: @macaroni : In that case, provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sheldore please check my edit 2, there is some progress

Comment: @macaroni : Try `plt.xlim([0, np.array(lines)[:,:,0].max()])` and the same for `ylim`. The problem is that `lines` is a list so you need to convert that to array for indexing

Comment: @Sheldore now is ```IndexError: too many indices for array``` for ```plt.xlim([0, np.array(lines)[:,:,0].max()])```

Comment: @macaroni : Try `print (np.array(lines).shape)` and tell me what does it print

Comment: @Sheldore ```print (np.array(lines).shape)``` print ```(31,)```