# Add label to LineCollection plot in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset from which I need to plot various, discontinuous, lines. Segments that belong to the same index within the dataset will have the same color. I have used the code provided in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352580/matplotlib-plotting-numerous-disconnected-line-segments-with-different-colors) as the base but due to the datastructure I have placed it in a loop:

```
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
color = ['r','g','b','c','y','k','m']
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
for i in indexset:
     lines=mc.LineCollection(data[i],colors=color[i])
     ax.addcollection(lines)
```

For each of the sets of lines, I would like to add a label/legend entry with the corresponding index i. Either a legend box with the index i next to the color of the line and/or the index as text within the graph. I tried adding a label=i argument within the loop, however then only the last index actually shows on the plot. How can I add a label for each index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your example doesn't contain test data, it is hard to guess the exact goal of the question. Here is an example that creates a legend of each set of lines. Note that data has 4 dimensions `(7, 5, 2, 2)`:

- the first, `7`, for 7 sets of lines
- the second, `5`, telling each set has 5 lines (or curves)
- the third, `2`, telling that each line consists of 2 vertices
- the fourth, `2`, being one for the `x` and one for the `y` coordinate

The code uses [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related), as the use of [`pylab` is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot) (already in 2012).

```py
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
from matplotlib import pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'k', 'm']
data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(len(colors), 5, 2, 2))
labels = [f'lines {i} ({c})' for i, c in enumerate(colors, start=1)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for d, col, label in zip(data, colors, labels):
    lines = mc.LineCollection(d, colors=col, label=label)
    ax.add_collection(lines)
ax.legend()
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is another example, with data created as:

```py
data = []
for _ in colors:
    t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, np.random.randint(5, 12), endpoint=False)
    x0, y0 = np.random.uniform(1, 9, 2)
    data.append(np.vstack([x0 + np.cos(t), y0 + np.sin(t), x0 + .1 * np.cos(t), y0 + .1 * np.sin(t)]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2))
```

[image: star example]

Comment: I received the following error message:  'LineCollection' object has no property 'labels'!

Comment: Perhaps you are running a rather old version of matplotlib?  I just tested it again with the now latest version (3.3.4) and it still works without error or warning.

Comment: It`s good notice. I am working with a proxy function to add labels. Cause the loop process, I created a class that gets the pick event.

Comment: My version was 3.3.1.Thanks.